# SFSE at Midwest Dreamin' 2014

Tags: discussion

Any other Stackexchanger's going to Midwest Dreamin' this week? I know [James Loghry](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/267/james-loghry) will be [presenting](http://midwestdreamin.com/sessions/salesforce-deployments/). Any others that I am missing? Should we have a SFSE meet and greet like they did at Dreamforce, where we can talk about how long we've been in beta? Any native (or former Chicagoans) have advice on places to eat?

Edit: I did miss at least one other one. [Kevin Poorman](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/332/kevin-p) will also be doing a [breakout session](http://midwestdreamin.com/sessions/apex-for-humans/)

Comment: Just to follow up on this, all the sessions mentioned above were great. The keynote from Peter Coffee was great, and I also attended breakouts by Andy Boettcher, Mark Ross, Steve Molis & Brad Gross, and all were excellent. If you are in the Midwest, you should definitely look at coming out next year.

Answer (score 1):

Not attending, just found out, sadly.  If you've never had a real Chicago deep dish pizza, you should find a Giordanos, and order a deep dish stuffed spinach + garlic pizza.  You will feel like you're levitating, even when you're too full to move.